# module for drag and drop on windows phone in titanium alloy app

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

Is there a titanium module to implement drag and drop in windows phone? I am using - https://github.com/animecyc/TiDraggable for Android and iOS, but can't find an equivalent for Windows.

Can anyone suggest any equivalent for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows SDK only very recently gained support for modules so there are not many modules available yet. Follow the [guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Windows_Module_Development_Guide) to create your own. There's probably some Windows example somewhere you can borrow the architecture from.